# Disable shortcode if status of value changes?

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

Looking to do enable or disable shortcode in a function, depending on a value. For instance, if someone says purchases a license key to use some shortcode on their site, I'd like to have the shortcode become disabled if they license expires. Example function I've been working on below:

```
my_premium_shortcodes(); // Fires early in my php file

function my_premium_shortcodes(){
    $status     = get_option( 'key_status' );

    if( $status !== false && $status == 'valid' ) { 

        add_shortcode('shortcode_handle_1','shortcode_function_1');
        add_shortcode('shortcode_handle_2','shortcode_function_2');

    } else {

        remove_shortcode('shortcode_handle_1','shortcode_function_1');
        remove_shortcode('shortcode_handle_2','shortcode_function_2');
    }

}
```

Any input on my approach or if the function should be handled in a separate way would be appreciated. As it stands, the shortcodes are working when everything is enabled, but stay enabled even after the 'status' changes to 'invalid'.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the code in two different functions instead of one single function. Please review below code and implement into your site.

```
$status     = get_option( 'key_status' );

if( $status !== false && $status == 'valid' ) {
//add a custom shortcode 
add_action( 'init', 'my_add_shortcodes' );
function my_add_shortcodes() {
add_shortcode( 'myShortcode', 'my_shortcode_function' );
}
else{
//which can also remove 
add_action( 'init', 'remove_my_shortcodes',20 );
function remove_my_shortcodes() {
remove_shortcode( 'myShortcode' );
}
```

Comment: Howdy, Keshav. Tried running this code and unfortunately it seems like the shortcode is stubbornly staying active, even after the value is changed. Even tried calling 'global $options;' just in case the get_option rule wasn't sure where to look and still the shortcode is stubbornly sticking around.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to post an update. The value of the status was apparently not properly being read by previous functions I had in my code. Essentially, just having my 'if' statement and removing the 'else' was all I needed to do.

So this works fine FYI:

```
function my_premium_shortcodes(){
$status     = get_option( 'key_status' );

if( $status !== false && $status == 'valid' ) { 

    add_shortcode('shortcode_handle_1','shortcode_function_1');
    add_shortcode('shortcode_handle_2','shortcode_function_2');

 } 
}
```

If the 'key_status' is actually being read, otherwise the shortcode was always firing.

Answer (score 0):

Add shortcode function code into the function.php file or in the plugin file.

```
    function my_add_shortcodes() {
        // Add your code here
    }
    add_shortcode( 'myShortcode', 'my_shortcode_function' );
```

Use the below condition to call the shortcode in any file of your theme.

```
$status     = get_option( 'key_status' );
if( $status !== false && $status == 'valid' ) {
    echo do_shortcode('[myShortcode]');
}
```

I hope it will help you.